# Using Apache beam Python SDK to update BigQuery Tables

Tags: google-bigquery, etl, data-warehouse, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Consider the following scenario: In Google BigQuery there are two tables "User" and "Order"

User table:

```
user_id           INTEGER
num_orders        INTEGER
last_updated_time TIMESTAMP
```

Order table:

```
user_id      INTEGER
order_id     INTEGER
created_time TIMESTAMP
```

The field "User.num_orders" is the total number of orders a user have so far and there is a daily Dataflow pipeline routine (written as a Google Cloud Dataflow Template and executed through REST API) which aggregates new orders in the previous day and increments the counter "User.num_orders".

My questions are the following:

1. There seems no update option in the python SDK. In package beam.io.BigQueryDisposition there are only 5 options:

   BigQueryDisposition options:

   ```
   CREATE_NEVER
   CREATE_IF_NEEDED
   WRITE_TRUNCATE
   WRITE_APPEND
   WRITE_EMPTY
   ```

   Right now I can think of a workaround solution by first summing new orders and appending these to an intermediate table "Intermediate"

   Intermediate table:

   ```
   user_id                 INTEGER
   intermediate_num_orders INTEGER
   created_time            TIMESTAMP
   ```

   At the end of the pipeline execution (after writing data to "Intermediate" table), we then issue a bigQuery update query to increment the counter "User.num_orders". The workaround is less obvious but doable and there is one pitfall in this method:

   Because it is a two-step operation (1. write to "Intermediate" table 2. update "User" table), we lost atomicity property of the entire process, which means step 2 might fail and special care must be taken to avoid any side effects (ex: If step 2 fails and we re-run the pipeline, some orders might be accumulated multiple times. This can be avoided by using timestamps but we as developers have to take care of it ourselves)
2. From 1. Is it a recommended way to use BigQuery? From data warehousing  management point of view (academically...), would it be better to avoid table updates completely and use "append only" operations? For example, we can aggregate daily orders, append them to "Intermediate" table, and compute the total on the fly (costs more money compared to table lookup if we store the overall value and records we currently have are at the scale of millions). This sounds like event sourcing pattern to me ...record every change as event and compute the current state by applying the events on the fly.

p.s. the example above is an over-simplified version of our current application and is for illustration purpose only. The real-life situation is way more complicated.